# Install failed ASP.NET Core Blazor Language Services

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core

I want to try the new Blazor platform using VS 2017 community edition but unable to install the extension. This is the log file generated while installing the plugin.

My .net frameowrk is 4.7.x and this extension requires framework 4.6.1 but I believe .net framework is backwards compatible so it must not be an issue.

```
Microsoft VSIX Installer
-------------------------------------------
vsixinstaller.exe version:
15.6.152+ge95e4dd1ce
-------------------------------------------
Command line parameters:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\vicky\Downloads\Microsoft.VisualStudio.BlazorExtension.vsix
-------------------------------------------
Microsoft VSIX Installer
-------------------------------------------
Initializing Install...
Extension Details...
    Identifier         : Microsoft.VisualStudio.BlazorExtension
    Name               : ASP.NET Core Blazor Language Services
    Author             : Microsoft
    Version            : 15.7.10237
    Description        : Provides Visual Studio support for ASP.NET Core Blazor
    Locale             : en-US
    MoreInfoURL        : 
    InstalledByMSI     : False
    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.6.1,)

    SignatureState     : ValidSignature
    SignedBy           : Microsoft Corporation
    Certificate Info   : 
        -------------------------------------------------------
        [Subject]       : CN=Microsoft Corporation, OU=OPC, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
        [Issuer]        : CN=Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
        [Serial Number] : 33000001FC5DB8191027A666C10000000001FC
        [Not Before]    : 05-10-2017 23:56:08
        [Not After]     : 05-10-2018 23:56:08
        [Thumbprint]    : 5E940B33DEAE5945F506ADAB946A997867A40FEF

    Supported Products : 
        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
            Version : [15.0.27512,16.0)

    References         : 
    Prerequisites      : 
        -------------------------------------------------------
        Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Web
        Name         : ASP.NET and web development tools
        Version      : [15.7.27520.0,16.0)

Signature Details...
    Extension is signed with a valid signature.

Searching for applicable products...
Found installed product - Global Location
Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017
VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
   at VSIXInstaller.App.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, Boolean isRepairSupported, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Comment: Which version of VS 2017 do you have installed? the Blazor language service requires at least a preview version of 15.7

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and Martin's suggestion of updating Visual Studio solved the problem. If the installer finds a product but the version # isn't the right one it throws a `VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException`.

I updated VS to 15.8.7 and was able to install the extension through the Visual Studio installer.

Comment: Thank you! this answer should be accepted. Updating my Visual Studio 2019 solved the problem for me.